# How to include the start date and end date while filtering in django

Tags: python, django

In `views.py`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
    f_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    print(f_date)
    to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
    t_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(t_date)
    check_box_status = request.POST.get("new_records", None)
    print(check_box_status)
    drop_down_status = request.POST.get("field")
    print(drop_down_status)
    if check_box_status is None:
        get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__range=(f_date, t_date))
```

The following code `get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(start_time__range=(f_date, t_date))` is unable to include the `t_date`. Is there any solution to include the `t_date`?

Comment: Instead: t_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1) Is there any option

Comment: Does `start_time__date__range=(f_date, t_date)` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Breaks.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```

Or if you are just trying to filter month wise:

```
Breaks.objects.filter(date__year='2011', 
              date__month='01')
```

Please reply to this message ,If it doesn't work.